# Using [[maybe_unused]] attribute on unused class *tors

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17

**Question**

Should I use `[[maybe_unused]]` [attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes#Standard_attributes) on unused class *tors?

​

**Example**

Let's consider the following example:

```js
public: struct keyData{
    public: [[maybe_unused]] keyData(){};
    public: keyData(::std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point timestamp)
        : lastMod(timestamp)
    {};

    protected: ::std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point lastMod = ::std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
};
```

I want to init multiple `keyData`s using cached [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) timestamps. However, I also provide argumentless constructor that inits `keyData`, setting `lastMod` to [`now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) as timestamp was not provided.

Should I mark unused `public: keyData(){};` with `[[maybe_unused]]` argument, as in example code, or not?

​

**Research**

`[[maybe_unused]]`​ description of [Standard attributes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes#Standard_attributes) site says *(bold is mine)*:

> **Appears in** the declaration of a class, a typedef­, a variable, a non­static data member, **a function**, an enumeration, or an enumerator. If the compiler issues warnings on unused entities, that warning is suppressed for any entity declared maybe_unused.

- [Constructors and member initializer
  lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)
  site says *(bold is mine)*:

  > **Constructor is a** special non-static member **function** of a class that is used to initialize objects of its class type.
- [Destructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)
  site says *(bold is mine)*:

  > **A destructor is a** special member **function** that is called when the lifetime of an object ends.
- [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)
  site says *(bold is mine)*:

  > Overloaded **operators are functions** with special function names.

So if I understood well, *tors are functions, and as functions they can be marked as `[[maybe_unused]]`, can't they?

Comment: Your code seems to have a bad case of Java/C#-itis. Symptoms include the incessant need to label *every* member declaration with an access class.

Comment: You also have an unnecessary leading `::` before `std`. If **anyone** were to declare a namespace `std::chrono` *not*  being the same as `::std::chrono` they would be fired immediately. Tar and feathers would also be appropriate. So the `::` in `::std` is not useful at all.

Comment: Not sure what was [that edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47582660/2), I hope it was a typo and not defacing of this question. Just in case though, if you wish to be de-associated to this answer, I think the correct course is to ask a moderator to do so through a custom-flag on the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use [[maybe_unused]] attribute on unused class *tors?

The purpose of `[[maybe_unused]]` is to prevent the emission of warnings for compilers that might warn about the qualified item being unused. Does your compiler warn about unused constructors? If so, then you should use it to suppress that warning.

But since most compilers don't warn about disused functions, it's best not to bother. The attribute would just be taking up space.

Unless you're advertising your library as being `-Wunused-member-function` clean, it's probably best for all involved that you not suppress this warning. After all, users who want to use that warning actually want the warning to be there. And users who don't use the warning don't need `[[maybe_unused]]` to be sprinkled around seemingly at random.

Comment: It's not about *mine* compiler. One may want to add `-Wunused` flag in future.

Comment: @Benio: And does that cause warnings on unused *constructors*? Because last time I checked, all of the -Wunused flags are about *variables*, not functions.

Comment: In today's edition of "Clang has a warning for everything," we introduce `-Wunused-member-function` (https://wandbox.org/permlink/z4mR22yroFpAkY9G).

Comment: Fun aside, I agree with the answer. I might add "If you don't ever compile code with this warning turned on, don't suppress the warning. Someone else may want to compile the code with this warning someday and expect to get a diagnostic for unused constructors. Do that person a favor and leave the warning alone."